# How to paint 2 gradients together on a Canvas?

Tags: delphi

Please look at this sample gradient image I did with a Paint program:

[image]

It contains 2 vertical gradients.

The first gradient from the top to the middle is a blend of white, to a lightly colored orange.

The second gradient from the bottom to the middle is also a blend of white, but to a slightly darker orange.

The point is there are 2 gradients been used, with 4 colors, 2 whites and 2 orange variations.

I would like to do this on a Canvas but don't know how to. The colors could be anything at all, above was just an example.

How may I do this?

Comment: Find a code to make a bi-color gradient and paint one from top from white to orange and below the second one from orange to white ?

Comment: what type of canvas do you use? GDI+ or Direct2D?

Comment: @TLama so that is the name of this type of gradient bi-color?

Comment: @teran just regular TCanvas like a form or paintbox etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Delphi 2005 and up:

Use [GradientFillCanvas](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/GraphUtil.GradientFillCanvas) from the *GraphUtil* unit:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  SetRect(R, 0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight div 2);
  GradientFillCanvas(Canvas, clWhite, $00056AFF, R, gdVertical);
  SetRect(R, 0, ClientHeight div 2, ClientWidth, ClientHeight); 
  GradientFillCanvas(Canvas, $000055FF, clWhite, R, gdVertical);
end;
```

---

#### Earlier Delphi versions:

Use [`GradientFill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144957(v=vs.85).aspx) from *Msimg32.dll*. Add the following code to a global utilities unit:

```
type
  PTriVertex = ^TTriVertex;
  TTriVertex = record
    X, Y: DWORD;
    Red, Green, Blue, Alpha: WORD;
  end;

function GradientFill(DC: HDC; Vertex: PTriVertex; NumVertex: ULONG;
  Mesh: Pointer; NumMesh, Mode: ULONG): BOOL; stdcall; overload;
  external msimg32 name 'GradientFill';

function GradientFill(DC: HDC; const ARect: TRect; StartColor,
  EndColor: TColor; Vertical: Boolean): Boolean; overload;
const
  Modes: array[Boolean] of ULONG = (GRADIENT_FILL_RECT_H, GRADIENT_FILL_RECT_V);
var
  Vertices: array[0..1] of TTriVertex;
  GRect: TGradientRect;
begin
  Vertices[0].X := ARect.Left;
  Vertices[0].Y := ARect.Top;
  Vertices[0].Red := GetRValue(ColorToRGB(StartColor)) shl 8;
  Vertices[0].Green := GetGValue(ColorToRGB(StartColor)) shl 8;
  Vertices[0].Blue := GetBValue(ColorToRGB(StartColor)) shl 8;
  Vertices[0].Alpha := 0;
  Vertices[1].X := ARect.Right;
  Vertices[1].Y := ARect.Bottom;
  Vertices[1].Red := GetRValue(ColorToRGB(EndColor)) shl 8;
  Vertices[1].Green := GetGValue(ColorToRGB(EndColor)) shl 8;
  Vertices[1].Blue := GetBValue(ColorToRGB(EndColor)) shl 8;
  Vertices[1].Alpha := 0;
  GRect.UpperLeft := 0;
  GRect.LowerRight := 1;
  Result := GradientFill(DC, @Vertices, 2, @GRect, 1, Modes[Vertical]);
end;
```

Now, the painting code becomes:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  SetRect(R, 0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight div 2);
  GradientFill(Canvas.Handle, R, clWhite, $00056AFF, True);
  SetRect(R, 0, ClientHeight div 2, ClientWidth, ClientHeight); 
  GradientFill(Canvas.Handle, R, $000055FF, clWhite, True);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;
```

[image: GradientFill.png]

Comment: There exists a wrapper for `GradientFill` already. In `GraphUtil.pas`: [`GradientFillCanvas`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/GraphUtil.GradientFillCanvas). You can use it similar, a call is also just one line. But where's the fun if you can code it yourself instead ;-)

Comment: @Chris It's not because I like coding when it's already done, but older Delphi versions do not have that routine.

Comment: I know - I was rather refering to my answer, as I basically implemented parts of the API function `GradientFill` which already exists and could be used instead :-)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if WinAPI code was an order of magnitude faster than the hand-written Delphi stuff.

Comment: +1 another good answer from the look of it, but as before I will need some time to read and understand what is going on with the code.

Comment: @Blobby, this one is now even better! Think about re-accept (sorry Chris), because to use the Delphi built-in function or Windows API is the most natural way to do so.

Comment: @TLama: I agree with you that the revised answer is better. If he does not want to do any modifications to the gradient, he should use this answer instead.

Comment: That does look really smooth. I don't want to take credit away from you Chris because you also did a good job, but if this method is better I will reaccept. Thank you both for providing solutions :)

Answer (score 7):

I coded it using a normal TCanvas.

The code draws a gradient on that canvas by steadily increasing the colors. You can adjust that for example by adding weights to either the start or the end color (e.g. to increase the white part).

```
procedure drawGradient(drawCanvas: TCanvas; canvasHeight, canvasWidth, canvasStartPos: Integer; startColor, endColor: TColor);
type
  RGBColor = (Blue, Green, Red);
var
  diff, startColorArray, endColorArray: array[RGBColor] of Integer;
  delta, currentColorFloat: array[RGBColor] of Double;
  gradientSize: Integer;
  currentColor: TColor;
  rgbC: RGBColor;
  i: Integer;
begin
  gradientSize := canvasHeight div 2;

  // Pre-calculate some required values for every RGB color
  for rgbC := Low(RGBColor) to High(RGBColor) do
    begin
    // Split the start end end colors into the RGB values
    // The right shift at the end shifts 16, 8 and 0 bits in the three loops
    // (I know that's a little hard to read)

    startColorArray[rgbC] := $FF and (startColor shr ((2 - Ord(rgbC)) * 8));
    endColorArray[rgbC] := $FF and (endColor shr ((2 - Ord(rgbC)) * 8));

    // Calculate the difference between the start and end color. This might be
    // a negative value, hence the declaration as Integer instead of Byte
    diff[rgbC] := startColorArray[rgbC] - endColorArray[rgbC];

    // And calculate a float value for each color. This is the increment on
    // every drawn line.
    delta[rgbC] := diff[rgbC] / gradientSize;
    end;

  // Initialize the drawn color with the start value
  currentColorFloat[Blue] := startColorArray[Blue];
  currentColorFloat[Green] := startColorArray[Green];
  currentColorFloat[Red] := startColorArray[Red];

  // Now draw the gradient line by line
  for i := 0 to gradientSize - 1 do
    begin
    // The target color as TColor
    currentColor := 0;

    for rgbC := Low(RGBColor) to High(RGBColor) do
      begin
      // Substract the decrement delta from the current color
      currentColorFloat[rgbC] := currentColorFloat[rgbC] - delta[rgbC];

      // Round the float value and left shift it to the correct position (16, 8 and 0 bits).
      // Then bitwise or it with the current color.
      currentColor := currentColor or (Round(currentColorFloat[rgbC]) shl ((2 - Ord(rgbC)) * 8));
      end;

    // Now draw a 1 pixel thin line from left to right
    drawCanvas.Pen.Color := currentColor;
    drawCanvas.MoveTo(0, i + canvasStartPos);
    drawCanvas.LineTo(canvasWidth, i + canvasStartPos);
    end;
end;
```

Call it like this:

```
procedure TForm18.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  white1: TColor = clWhite;
  white2: TColor = $00CFCFCF;
  color1: TColor = $000080FF;
  color2: TColor = $00007AF4;
begin
  // pb is a TPaintbox, but this works with any canvas

  drawGradient(pb.Canvas, pb.Height, pb.Width, 0, white1, color1);
  drawGradient(pb.Canvas, pb.Height, pb.Width, pb.Height div 2, color2, white2);
end;
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: +1 Looks very good thank you Chris. I will try this out and will probably have some further questions to ask about the code etc..

Comment: I added some comments for better understanding (and fixed an error, I used `pb.Width` at the end and replaced that by an additional parameter instead).

Comment: +1 the comments make it a lot easier for me to try and understand.

Comment: could you suggest to me any really good articles on Graphics. The above you posted I still find difficult to understand even with the comments. I need to understand the basics before I can understand how your solution works :)

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know of a specific article I could recommend. The above code is basically some rather simple math (it adds a fixed number to a color value on each line). I'm sure you will find some good articles using google (e.g. the [wikipedia article on gradients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient) looks good)

Comment: See also [efg's Delphi reference library, graphics part](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/index.html) for more input about working on a canvas.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. it might take me some time to understand how these things work but I guess have to start somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

I like to use class helpers on TCanvas so I revised the code in the other answer.

```
type
  TTriVertex = record
  public
    type
      P = ^TTriVertex;
  public
    X, Y: DWORD;
    Red, Green, Blue, Alpha: WORD;
    constructor Create(APoint: TPoint; AColor: TColor; AAlpha: Word = 0);
  end;

  TTriVertexRect = record
  public
    TopLeft: TTriVertex;
    LowerRight: TTriVertex;
    constructor Create(ARect: TRect; Color1,Color2; AAlpha1: Word = 0; AAlpha2: Word = 0);
  end;
 {Enumerate the constants so they will show up on alt space in the IDE}
 TGradientFillType = (
     gftRectH = GRADIENT_FILL_RECT_H
    ,gftRectV = GRADIENT_FILL_RECT_V
    ,gftTriangle = GRADIENT_FILL_TRIANGLE);

 TCavas_Helper = class helper for TCanvas
  public
    function GradientFill(const Vertexes: array of TTriVertexRect; FillType: TGradientFillType): Boolean; overload;
  end;

{ TTriVertex }

constructor TTriVertex.Create(APoint: TPoint; AColor: TColor; AAlpha: Word = 0);
begin
  X := APoint.X;
  Y := APoint.Y;
  Red := GetRValue(ColorToRGB(AColor)) SHL 8;
  Green := GetGValue(ColorToRGB(AColor)) SHL 8;
  Blue := GetBValue(ColorToRGB(AColor)) SHL 8;
  Alpha := 0;
end;

{ TTriVertexRect }

constructor TTriVertexRect.Create(ARect: TRect; Color1, Color2: TColor; AAlpha1,
  AAlpha2: Word);
begin
  TopLeft.Create(ARect.TopLeft,Color1,AAlpha1);
  LowerRight.Create(ARect.BottomRight,Color2,AAlpha2);
end;

{ TCavas_Helper }

function TCavas_Helper.GradientFill(const Vertexes: array of TTriVertexRect; FillType: TGradientFillType): Boolean;
var
  GRect: array of TGradientRect;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(GRect,Length(Vertexes));
  for Index := 0 to Length(GRect) do begin
    GRect[Index].UpperLeft := Index*2;
    GRect[Index].LowerRight := Index*2 + 1;
  end;
  Result := WIndows.GradientFill(Handle,@Vertexes[0],Length(Vertexes)*2,@GRect[0],Length(GRect),Ord(FillType))
end;
```

So the actual call looks like this

```
procedure TForm56.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Canvas.GradientFill([
      TTriVertexRect.Create(Rect(0,0,ClientWidth,ClientHeight DIV 2),clWhite,$00056AFF)
     ,TTriVertexRect.Create(Rect(0,ClientHeight DIV 2,ClientWidth,ClientHeight),$00056AFF,clWhite)
    ],gftRectV);
end;
```

Sample:

[image: Sample]

Answer (score -2):

```
iWidth: Integer;
iWidth := Width div 2;
GradientFillCanvas(Canvas, Col1, Col2, Rect(0, 0, iWidth, Height), gdHorizontal);
GradientFillCanvas(Canvas, Col2, Col1, Rect(iWidth, 0, Width, Height),gdHorizontal);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question!  Code-only answers [are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274) on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it impossible for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it.  Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer.

Comment: This information was already posted (with a full explanation) in a post 3 years ago. With absolutely no explanation and no details added, what is the purpose of simply duplicating that information here?