# Which property of TPanel is to be used to get this shadow?

Tags: user-interface, delphi

I would like to know how the shadow effect has been implemented in the Get It Package Manager window. The shadow area is marked red.

Is there any property in TPanel to achieve this or is it custom drawn?
[image]

Comment: There is no built-in property of `TPanel` to achieve this. This screenshot is either using custom controls, or not even made in Delphi at all. It's also possible that might be a simple `TImage` with a gradient assigned as its picture.

Comment: I can confirm the screenshot is of a real Delphi-made screen, and it uses 3 standard `TPanel` objects (which then have other controls inside of them). There is no `TImage` involved, and there are no controls between the top `TPanel` and the lower `TPanel`s.  I *suspect* the effect is most likely done by defining a bottom `Margin` underneath the top `TPanel` and then custom-drawing a gradient (maybe with `GraphUtil.GradientFillCanvas()`) onto the parent Form within that margin area, such as with the form's `OnPaint` event.

Comment: @JerryDodge: "or not even made in Delphi at all."  Possible, but unlikely as the manager is contained in GetIt230.Bpl (for Seattle).

Comment: @MartynA Yes, that was from before I realized what that app actually was. And Remy has already confirmed it is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no property of `TPanel` to create that shadow.

Using Spy++, I can see the GetIt Package Manager window uses 3 standard `TPanel` objects (which then have other controls inside of them), and there are no other controls between the top `TPanel` object and the two lower `TPanel` objects.

I *suspect* the effect is most likely done by defining a bottom `Margin` underneath the top `TPanel` and then custom-drawing a gradient (such as with `GraphUtil.GradientFillCanvas()`) onto the parent Form within that margin area.

I was able to reproduce the effect in 10.0 Seattle using the following test code:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Panel3: TPanel;
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  GraphUtil;

procedure TForm2.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  R := ClientRect;
  R.Top := Panel1.Top + Panel1.Height;
  R.Bottom := Panel2.Top;
  GradientFillCanvas(Canvas, clGray, clWhite, R, gdVertical);
end;

end.
```

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 266
  ClientWidth = 622
  Color = clWhite
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnPaint = FormPaint
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Panel1: TPanel
    AlignWithMargins = True
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 622
    Height = 41
    Margins.Left = 0
    Margins.Top = 0
    Margins.Right = 0
    Align = alTop
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    Caption = 'Panel1'
    ParentBackground = False
    TabOrder = 0
    ExplicitLeft = 224
    ExplicitTop = 128
    ExplicitWidth = 185
  end
  object Panel2: TPanel
    AlignWithMargins = True
    Left = 0
    Top = 47
    Width = 185
    Height = 219
    Margins.Left = 0
    Margins.Bottom = 0
    Align = alLeft
    Caption = 'Panel2'
    TabOrder = 1
    ExplicitLeft = 224
    ExplicitTop = 128
    ExplicitHeight = 41
  end
  object Panel3: TPanel
    AlignWithMargins = True
    Left = 191
    Top = 47
    Width = 431
    Height = 219
    Margins.Right = 0
    Margins.Bottom = 0
    Align = alClient
    Caption = 'Panel3'
    TabOrder = 2
    ExplicitLeft = 224
    ExplicitTop = 128
    ExplicitWidth = 185
    ExplicitHeight = 41
  end
end
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: And here I was in the middle of writing an answer manually drawing the gradient - thanks for pointing to the `GraphUtil` unit!

Comment: @JerryDodge: I was about to do the same thing, and then I found this: [How to paint 2 gradients together on a Canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532549/).  Looking back, it turns out that the `GraphUtil` unit has been around since D6, but `GradientFillCanvas()` was not added to it until sometime during D8-D2006 (it exists in D2006, but I don't have sources for D8-D2005 to check).

Comment: It was apparently added in Delphi 2005. But OP appears to be using one of the Delphi 10 versions, so it should be fine.

Comment: Excellent answer. Works as expected.